# error: inlining failed in call to always_inline '_mm_aesenc_si128': target specific option mismatch, adding -msse4.1 not enough

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross-compile the cryptonote gui wallet from Linux (Fedora) to Windows.

When compiling without any additional flags, I get this error :

```
In file included from /home/etienne/Documents/Brokertech/bkc/brokercoins/guiwallet-win/cryptonote/src/crypto/slow-hash.c:9:0:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/include/emmintrin.h:1290:1: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline '_mm_xor_si128': target specific option mismatch
  _mm_xor_si128 (__m128i __A, __m128i __B)
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/etienne/Documents/Brokertech/bkc/brokercoins/guiwallet-win/cryptonote/src/crypto/slow-hash.c:100:11: note: called from here
   *tmp3 = _mm_xor_si128(*tmp3, tmp4);
```

I then tried to add -msse4.1 flags for C and CXX, and I still got the same error, but on a different file :

```
In file included from 
/home/etienne/Documents/Brokertech/bkc/brokercoins/guiwallet-win/cryptonote/src/crypto/slow-hash.c:10:0:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/include/wmmintrin.h:61:1: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline '_mm_aesenc_si128': target specific option mismatch
   _mm_aesenc_si128 (__m128i __X, __m128i __Y)
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from 
/home/etienne/Documents/Brokertech/bkc/brokercoins/guiwallet-win/cryptonote/src/crypto/slow-hash.c:167:0:
/home/etienne/Documents/Brokertech/bkc/brokercoins/guiwallet-win/cryptonote/src/crypto/slow-hash.inl:159:21: note: called from here
   xmminput[0] = _mm_aesenc_si128(xmminput[0], expkey[j]);
```

I don't get why the solution worked on the first file but is now blocking ?
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't get the same error. You got 2 **completely distinct errors**. The first inlining failure is for a SSE-**2** 128-bit XOR instruction that did get resolved by adding `-msse4.1`. The second one is an [AES NI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set) intrinsic, for which I believe you need `-maes`